# Write Text ontop of an Image dynamically in ASP.NET MVC3

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, graphics

How would I write Text ontop of an image, and if possible, at an angle.

So, the box is the origional image. 64x64 for example.

And I want to write text on it for example `test`

It needs to be rotated ~30 degrees as seen. and If possible too, leaning away at the top.[image]

So that It seems like it is written on the surface.

I have no experience with C# Graphics, and would like some help please. 
Please include any using references for my ease.

Comment: This seems way too "give me teh codez"

Comment: Sorry, any ideas or direction pointing will be much appreciated. I was just hoping for examples of each point, i.e. rotation etc, else I would still be at square one with no idea on how to achieve it.

Comment: Do you want to do this server side or client side?

Comment: Server side. Its an Icon (png format) I wish to display.

Comment: Do you need to rotate both the text and the image, or is the image already rotated and you want to write text on it (at an angle)?

Comment: Just the text. Image is rotated. Just trying to write dynamic text onto of an existing image. :)

Comment: Your options are probably GDI/GDI+ and WPF.  I don't have much experience doing it so I'll leave that to someone who does, but it should at least point you in the right search direction.

Comment: Bear in mind, that writing text onto an already slanted image and making it look good is pretty hard.  Especially if the images are slanted to different degrees...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use JavaScript and jQuery functions and Css 3.0 to update add a div containing your text ontop of the image and then rotate it.
this [link](http://css-tricks.com/text-blocks-over-image/) may help you to reach your goal

Comment: Using your concept. I created a Div that uses a background. Then just wrote my text into the div. :)  `.FileIcon{    
 background: url('images/FileIcons/folder.png') left no-repeat;
   background-position: 1px 1px; 
   height: 64px;
   width: 64px;
   color:White;
   vertical-align: middle;
   text-align:center;
   font-weight:bold;
   }`